# Are HTTP headers (Content-Type, &c.) case-sensitive?

Tags: http, http-headers, content-type

Perhaps I'm skimming too fast, but couldn't find this specifically documented. In my particular case, I'm wondering about the "Content-Type" header, but I'm assuming the same rules would apply to other standard headers.

**Are these case sensitive, and if so: Is it `Content-Type` or `Content-type`?**

Is there a proper place to reference these?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Case-insensitive.**

[Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

> 4.2 Message Headers
>
> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
>   request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
>   entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
>   that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
>   of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. **Field names
>   are case-insensitive.**

Comment: Are field values case-insensitive too??

Comment: With rare exceptions they are too case-insensitive, however you need to check with `RFC` each time you are in doubts.

Comment: Tell me if application/pdf and application/PDF are equal ?? I assume no..

Comment: MIME types are interpreted case-insensitively.

Comment: For ref on MIME types case sensitivity: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-5.1

Answer (score 26):

Looks like the MIME type in a Content-type header value is case-insensitive, so application/PDF and application/pdf **are** equivalent. It does say parameter values are case-sensitive, so technically "text/html; charset=UTF-8" is not equivalent to "text/html; charset=utf-8". But that's not a good example because http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.1 says "Names for character encodings are case-insensitive".

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html

> The type, subtype, and parameter names are not case sensitive. For
>   example, TEXT, Text, and TeXt are all equivalent. Parameter values are
>   normally case sensitive, but certain parameters are interpreted to be
>   case- insensitive, depending on the intended use. (For example,
>   multipart boundaries are case-sensitive, but the "access- type" for
>   message/External-body is not case-sensitive.)

Comment: Note that RFC 1341 has been obsoleted by RFC 2045.  However the text relating to case sensitivity quoted from RFC 1341 doesn't seem to have changed in RFC 2045.

Comment: @SimonTewsi I couldn't find this info in RFC 2045. It seems [RFC 7231 section 3.1.1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1) is the correct one.

Comment: @Arendv.Reinersdorff:  See [RFC 2045 section 5.1, Syntax of the Content-Type Header Field](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-5.1).  It's on the second page of the section.

Comment: @SimonTewsi Thanks for pointing it out, I missed it :-)