# In header(), is 'Content-Type' === 'Content-type' as far as sending duplicate/replacing headers is concerned?

Tags: php, http-headers

In PHP, the documentation says that you can replace previously set headers via the second, boolean, argument to `header()`.

I'm wondering: Are HTTP headers case-sensitive or normalized in any way?

If I use:

```
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    header('Content-type: text/html');
```

... will it send one, or two different headers?

Similarly, if I use:

```
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    header('Content-type: text/html', TRUE);
```

... will that (properly?) replace the first?

Comment: You can test it with your browser's developer tool. Run a script with your given lines, and check the response headers the browser receives.

Comment: Judging by your previous question, are you having a problem related to this topic? If so... just post your problem directly; you'll get an answer faster if you just ask the real question.

Comment: "Real problem" is alleged by someone that part of an app is sending multiple "Content-type" headers. My presumption is that they are wrong. Rather than guess around, I started researching, and asked the HTTP-specific question. I followed up by adding this PHP-specific version to add to the community more google-able results; also, in the event that someone might present a particular peculiarity with PHP that might have slipped by other assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html), HTTP header field names are case-insensitive.

PHP does get this right, and replaces the first header with the second.

Comment: This was mentioned in an answer to [his previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718476/are-http-headers-content-type-c-case-sensitive) - this question kinda sorta asks if PHP complies with it.