# 400 Bad Request only using AngularJs, works with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, rest

I am having troubles using `AngularJs` for a specific "PUT" Ajax request (RESTFul service).

The same piece of code works with `jQuery` and plain JavaScript.

```
$http({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/api.php?rquest=updateUuid",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "text/plain",
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(email + ":" + password)
    },
    data: {
        Email: email,
        Uuid: login_response.uuid
    }
}).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});


jQuery.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/api.php?rquest=updateUuid",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "text/plain",
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(email + ":" + password)
    },
    data: {
        Email: email,
        Uuid: login_response.uuid
    }
}).done(function(response){
    console.log(response)
});
```

The server is responding with a `JSON` object, but the first code (`AngularJs`) seems to work a bit differently.
Before I wasn't setting the Content-Type header and I was getting a CORS issue (worked with `jQuery`, but `AngularJs` was setting the content-type to "application/json" and was causing an error).

I got the first part fixed setting the content-type to text/plain, but now I'm getting a `400 Bad Request Error` (only with `AngularJs`). I also tried to delete the transformRequest using an interceptor, but it didn't work.

Am I using `AngularJs` wrong? Because I'm thinking that, unlinke `jQuery`, it is doing extra "stuff" in the background, making some extra headers or not passing the data correctly.

Usually I get that error when I do not pass any data to the RESTful service.

I am learning `AngularJs`, so I'd rather use it instead of `jQuery`.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use Wireshark to see exactly what headers are being passed in each case.

Comment: Just compare what headers are sent in both cases. There is a difference.

Comment: I considered to do that, but I was debugging that with an interceptor, logging the config object of every call, and the response.

From what I've seen it appears that everything is correct, but actually it's not working

Comment: Best to compare what's actually on the "wire". If not Wireshark, use developer tools at least.

Comment: I think it should be  Content-Type  not   Content-type  .But maybe this is not the reason and it is because they converting the data object differently

Comment: @micha HTTP headers are case insensitive.

Comment: I got it, jQuery was automatically serializing the data object to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, AngularJs wasn't...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718476/are-http-headers-content-type-c-case-sensitive  field names are case-insensitive ok got it

Comment: Yes, the content-type field had a lowecase letter, but that wasn't causing the error in this case.
The data was not serialized by AngularJs automatically, unlinke jQuery which did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, jQuery was automatically serializing the data object to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, AngularJs wasn't...

Working Code:

```
$http({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/api.php?rquest=updateUuid",
    headers: {
        Accept: "*/*",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(email + ":" + password)
    },
    data: jQuery.param({
        Email: email,
        Uuid: login_response.uuid
    })
})
```

Anyway this doesn't look so well, but it's working at least..
Anybody knows a better way to get AngularJs to send serialized data as x-www-form-urlencoded?